# ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup only when using a specific citation in LateX

Tags: latex, biblatex

When I compile the code below I get the following error : "! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.29 }".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, natbib=true, sorting = none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{CARRTEL.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}


\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}



\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}




\newenvironment{sciabstract}{%
\begin{quote} \bf}
{\end{quote}}




\title{Internship report} 





\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{gobble}
% Double-space the manuscript.

\baselineskip24pt



\maketitle 

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage





\section*{Abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Study site}

Lake Murten, also known as Lake Morat, is located in Switzerland in the Seeland region (the Three Lakes region), nested between the Alps and the Jura mountains on the Swiss Plateau.
It covers an area of 22.8 km$^{2}$ and possesses a volume of 0.55 km$^{3}$. Its surface altitude is 429 meters above sea level. The catchment area is considered to be 693 km$^{2}$. \\
Historically speaking, this region of the Swiss Plateau is rich in archaeological sites covering the last 10000 years.
The very first traces of modern humans living in this area date back to 8,000 years before the Common Era (BCE) \cite{international__swiss_wetzikon_nodate}, but more extensive occupation really started around 4300 BCE \cite{bolliger_archaeological_2020, international_and_swiss_coordination_group_unesco_palafittes_111_nodate, mondial_sites_nodate}.




\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography




\end{document}
```

I have narrowed it down to the fact that the following citation seemingly breaks things, but I have no idea why :
`\cite{international__swiss_wetzikon_nodate}`.

The .bib entry for this reference is as follows :

```
@online{international__swiss_wetzikon_nodate,
    title = {Wetzikon {\textbar} Robenhausen},
    url = {https://palafittes.org/fundstelle-en.html?sid=220},
    abstract = {Short {DescriptionThe} site at Pfäffiker Lake was discovered in 1858 by Jakob Messikommer, an early pile dwelling researcher. The site is known especially for a wooden door, dated to the Pfyn culture, as well as countless textile artifacts. Many well preserved woven textiles and fishing- and carrying nets were discovered, as well as parts of a Neolithic loom.},
    author = {International {\textbackslash}\& Swiss},
    urldate = {2023-12-08},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\Manuel\\Zotero\\storage\\Q9KII9DM\\fundstelle-en.html:text/html},
}
```

I am a relatively new user so it is very possible I have missed something obvious but I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an corporate author, you should input it as `{{...}}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, natbib=true, sorting = none]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@online{international__swiss_wetzikon_nodate,
    title = {Wetzikon {\textbar} Robenhausen},
    url = {https://palafittes.org/fundstelle-en.html?sid=220},
    abstract = {Short {DescriptionThe} site at Pfäffiker Lake was discovered in 1858 by Jakob Messikommer, an early pile dwelling researcher. The site is known especially for a wooden door, dated to the Pfyn culture, as well as countless textile artifacts. Many well preserved woven textiles and fishing- and carrying nets were discovered, as well as parts of a Neolithic loom.},
    author = {{International \& Swiss}},
    urldate = {2023-12-08},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\Manuel\\Zotero\\storage\\Q9KII9DM\\fundstelle-en.html:text/html},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document} 

\cite{international__swiss_wetzikon_nodate}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why that is the correct way to input it?

Comment: @MT74 Normally, biblatex expects the author field to be something like `{Albert Einstein and Donald Duck}` and will split it into the different authors and further into their name parts to format them depending on the used style. If you have an corporate author, you will want to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
However when I add that to my code all the citations disappear and I get warning messages such as 'Citation undefined'.

Comment: @MT74 Does the code as it is from my answer work for on your system?

Comment: Yes, and now I don't get the errors in my main file, but the author still appears with {and}.